# Laravel - change route in middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-8

Let's say I have this kind of URLs :

```
example.com/en/
example.com/en/login
example.com/fr/login
```

I would like to use a middleware to set the language and then return the route to be handled without the language part. So the router would get `/` or `/login`, without any language stuff.

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        // $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4));// not working

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: check this https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Comment: Thanks but it won't help me. I need to be able to handle it from the middleware, working for the whole app, since it's not possible to make what is shown in your article for routes coming from jetstream for example.

Comment: you will need to use the session/cookie/query string to dictate what the locale would be after you redirect to the URL without the locale in the path

Comment: Wrong. If you set the locale with `setLocale` you can use it even if it's not in cookies or anything, the app knows it already.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the language in session and use a middleware to setLocale.

Working example

SetLocale.php middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('language'))
    {
        App::setLocale(strtolower(Session::get('language')));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Controller function to set language to session

```
 public function setLanguage(string $language)
{
    if (Session::has('language'))
    {
        Session::forget('language');
    }
    Session::put('language', $language);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

So now on everything that happens on the website, the middleware will check the language and set it to what's in session.

Also don't forget to specify the middleware in $middlewareGroups in app\Http\Kernel.php

You can create a form anywhere on website for the user to choose his language preference with a route to the controller function.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I'm not trying to use sessions - I can do that, sure, but I specifically need the locale to be handled in the url - and there are a few urls I don't have real control over so I can't prefix them.